# Properties that are read-only, but only outside of the class

Tags: c#, class, properties, readonly, getter-setter

Is there a way to create a property that can be changed within the class, but still accessed with `objectName.propertyName` outside of it? I'm curious if I can access the property without a get method and still not be able to change it outside of the class.

Obviously, `readonly` doesn't work, because it restricts changes within the class as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set a different access level on `get`or `set`. So this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string MyStringProperty
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

gives you a property that can only be read on the outside, but set by the class itself.